# Angular routing logic within feature module

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-module

Assume that I have this routes in my feat-module

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'create',
    component: CreateAnnouncementComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'edit/:id',
    component: CreateAnnouncementComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'list',
    component: AnnouncementListComponent
  }
];
```

This feat-module is imported from the `home-routing.module`

```
{
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'announcement',
        loadChildren: () => import('../announcement/announcement.module').then(mod => mod.AnnouncementModule)
      }
    ]
  }
```

So we have routes like *'/home/announcement/create'* etc

From `CreateAnnouncementComponent` I want to navigate to `AnnouncementListComponent` but `CreateAnnouncementComponent` is reachable from two different routes, */create* and */edit/:id*. This won't let me use relative navigation, like:

```
this.router.navigate(['../list'], {relativeTo: this.activeRoute});
```

because in the edit case the new route will be */announcement/edit/list* instead of /announcement/list, as the ':id' in the url add one level to the route.

Question is: how can I instruct the `announcmenetCreateComponent` to move to the 'list' route without use absolutes path like 'home/announcement/list' and without implementing logic to read and split the actual path?

Answer (score 0):

You can attack this from another direction using Angular's [Location](https://angular.io/api/common/Location) utility.

```
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

...

constructor(
    private location: Location,
    private router: Router,
) {}

navigateToList () {
    const url = this.location.path().indexOf('edit') > -1
        ? '/announcement/edit/list' : '/announcement/list';
    this.router.navigate([url], { relativeTo: this.activeRoute });
}
```

Comment: but this implies to actually implement logic to read the actual path. Is possible to navigate from a route to another without this?

Comment: Yes: this.router.navigate(['..', 'list'], {relativeTo: this.activeRoute});, but keep in mind that this locks you into relative routing, which, depending on your use case, can be very limiting. If this component is only for announcements, and isn't a generic form->list path, then absolute paths will allow you to reuse the component in multiple locations in your app.

Comment: No, I can't. As said, relative navigation don't match all the use cases, cause I call the same component in two different route levels: '/create' and '/edit/:id